# Removed Ubuntu 16.04, Unable to boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

UPDATE: I got into windows and told it to reset to factory settings.  Ran forever and then booted back into the grub screen.  Now I cannot get back into windows.

Here is what I have:  Windows 8 installed.  Ubuntu and Grub installed but then Ubuntu removed.  I have no Linux.  I am pretty new with Linux and have no idea what to do.  The computer does not have a CD and I cannot get it to boot from a USB.
Thoughts?

I recently installed Ubuntu 16 next to windows 8.1.  I used this article to help with the process. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

I had everything working great on Ubuntu and messed up a driver install.  I wanted to do a fresh install and make the partition for Ubuntu larger.

Inside windows, I removed the Ubuntu partition and created another larger one.  Then when I went to reboot I get a Grub command promt.  I cannot get either my windows recovery usb or my live Ubuntu usb to load.  I cannot enter the bios for the machine.  When I click F8, Fn+Esc, F12, F2, etc they all take me to Dell Enhanced Preboot Assement tool.

I need help.  Right now the machine is useless.

Thanks
eric

Comment: You need to boot from Windows Recovery (or installation) media and repair the bootloader. The guide you followed has lots of issues and the worst one is that you ended up with a BIOS install, hence the problem when you deleted the Ubuntu partition. You also learn something: Never do that! You don't partition from Windows (Windows doesn't recognize the EXT partitions). At most, from Windows, you would be shrinking the partition(s) even more, then reboot and let it perform a checkdisk (chkdsk). Then boot Ubuntu live media as usual and use "something else" to manage partitions for Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I def learned something.  I have a windows recovery usb, but it will not boot.  Goes straight to grub.  Even if I do all the normal key strokes to get to the bios. I am still looking at the links in the post from Nijboer

Comment: Update:  I was finally able to get to windows.  So now I will fix everything and then install ubuntu again

Answer (score 0):

This means grub is fine, but it can't find the configuration. The following links should help you out. It takes some reading but explains how to go from here.

https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

U dont need to deal with windows for now....dont worry installing Ubuntu back in the unallocated memory will install ubuntu along with grub...when u deleted ubuntu partitions from windows...u deleted grub along with it...so it will show "grub rescue error" because windows bootloader was overwritten by grub and now it cant find grub...(simply:u deleted grub not windows)
Just install ubuntu just like u did before along side windows and u will get ur system back :)  with windows...dont keeo doing stuffs like repairing windows boot loader... anyways when u will install ubuntu it will get erased so why install?go for ubuntu directly